# python: virtualenv/wrapper ignores VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I am trying to tell virtualenvwrapper to use `python3.4` instead of `python2.7` which is mapped to python.

Unfortunately `virtualenvwrapper` ignores `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` and always uses `python2.7`.

I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728652/virtualenvwrapper-seemingly-ignoring-virtualenvwrapper-python)

And none of what was mentioned there helped me.

I installed all the tools using `pip3`

```
[root@server]# pip3 install virtualenv setuptools virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (16.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (40.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenvwrapper in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (0.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: stevedore in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper) (1.29.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper) (1.11.0)
```

And not `pip`:

```
[root@server]# pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
Skipping virtualenvwrapper as it is not installed.
```

And I also set the env-variables before making a venv:

```
[dakes@server .virtualenvs]$ export |grep -i virtual
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR="/home/dakes/.virtualenvs"
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=".project"
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4"
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT="/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV="/usr/local/bin/virtualenv"
declare -x VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD="1"
declare -x WORKON_HOME="/home/dakes/.virtualenvs"
```

But everytime I create a venv it uses `python2.7`, as you can see in line 3:

```
[dakes@server ~]$ mkdir virtualenvtest
[dakes@server ~]$ mkvirtualenv test -a virtualenvtest/
New python executable in /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/dakes/.virtualenvs/test/bin/get_env_details
Setting project for test to /home/dakes/virtualenvtest
```

What am I doing wrong?

**/edit:**

I was able to solve this by adding

```
export VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=${VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON}
```

to my .bashrc

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper in /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (4.8.2)` != `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3.4"` & `[root@server]` != `[dakes@server ~]`. bad practice to use root to install.

Comment: @cryptonome the wrappers [install doc](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) says `virtualenvwrapper should be installed into the same global site-packages area where virtualenv is installed. You may need administrative privileges to do that.`. so I am not sure how I should have installed it. puthon3.4 is installed via yum.